# find value from API callback url

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using an API for sending sms in my site. As per their documentation, the API structure is as follows:

```
http://example.com/api/swsend.asp?username=xxxx&password=xxxx&sender=senderId&sendto=919xxxx,919xxxx&message=hello&dlrUrl=http://yourServer_Url?logID=$logID$%26phNo=$phNO$%26result=$result$
```

the message sending part is OK. But I am confused with Callback url. My function for callback is as follows:

```
public function sendMessageCallback() {        

    $responseBody = file_get_contents('php://input');  

    $data = array('value' => $responseBody, 'date' => date('Y-m-d h:i:s'));
    $this->db->insert('test1', $data);
}
```

and so my api call is like
`http://example.com/api/swsend.asp?username=xxxx&password=xxxx&sender=senderId&sendto=919xxxx,919xxxx&message=hello&dlrUrl=http://example.in/API/sendMessageCallback`

But nothing is written to DB.

Comment: Have you tried `var_dump($responseBody)`? If you have and that yielded correct results try turning db_debug to true in the database.php file

Comment: @Alex My site is already live. So I can't turn on the debug option.

Comment: That's what local development is for... Do it there. If you can't, then I'm not sure how you expect us to be able to help you debug this. I take it that the var_dump is as you expect, or can you not do that also?

Comment: `var_dump($responseBody)` prints `string(0) "" `

Comment: Well there is your problem ;) Find out why your api call is not returning anything. Typically get the contents `http://someapi.com/api?blah` with curl (apis usually returns something like json) and then you can conform that data and enter it in your db. As I have 0 info on what api you are using I cannot say how to access its data, but I doubt post is the way.

Comment: Normally you can also open an API call in a browser which is even easier to diagnose the problem (unless its tied to a specific IP address).

Answer (score 0):

I thing your problem is in PHP configuration.

Check that the server allows you to open remote URLs with the file functions (the php.ini "allow_url_fopen" setting must be "true").

If it is allow then you can try PHP cURL.